# Unable to override rspec_opts in test-kitchen/busser-serverspec

Tags: test-kitchen, serverspec

It seems that there's way to override rspec_opts. By default it is running with "--color --format documentation", like such:

```
/opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby -I/tmp/verifier/suites/serverspec -I/tmp/verifier/gems/gems/rspec-support-3.3.0/lib:/tmp/verifier/gems/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib /opt/chef/embedded/bin/rspec --pattern /tmp/verifier/suites/serverspec/\*\*/\*_spec.rb --color --format documentation --default-path /tmp/verifier/suites/serverspec
```

Is there a way to disable color and execute in format json and documentation?

I've tried adding a .rspec file in the test directory but Test Kitchen doesn't pick that up. I've also tried to move the .rspec file into suite/serverspec directory and still the busser is running with --color and --format documentation.

Any ideas how to disable the color and format it in json and documentation?

Thanks!